# Dedicated keyboard, mouse and monitor for a virtual machine

Tags: virtualization

I am planning on building a classroom enviroment using VMWare to create virtual machines. I need to have a dedicated keyboard, monitor and mouse for each virtual machine. The guests will be running Windows 2008 Server. I plan on having two large blade systems on which the VMs will be built. Each blade would have 5 VMs. Can this be done?

Comment: Wouldn’t you still need some sort of “host” client to access the VM’s via remote desktop (or something like it)?

Comment: This is basically "Desktop as a Service" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_virtualization

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may need to invest in some [thin-clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client).